# Youtube Data API v3 Quota - Change of Domain / Oauth App

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Currently, my YouTube API quota is associated with a Google Cloud project that will be changing.

I am wondering how I should go about this to ensure that I will not violate guidelines, as I will be creating a new OAuth app and wanted to see if I could associate this YouTube API with this one.

For reference we have had a quota increase on this YouTube API and we currently have active users on the domain we will be wanting to change.

Nothing will be different about the application; we are simply just changing the domain of our software.

Through the domain change, I am wondering about the best way to approach this. Should I just repeat this process, or whom should I notify about the current app, etc.?

I have done nothing yet, as I do not want to violate Youtube API guidelines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.